# Accessing device at kernel level

Tags: api, kernel, embedded, driver, xilinx

I have a Xilinx PCI Express device that operates in a request-reply manner, and that can handle requests depending on what FPGA logic you implement there. Really nice.

Also it comes with a free open-source driver code (operating at kernel level) available online at https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/65444.html

This device has user-space API but no kernel-level API. And since my project requires me to have everything at kernel level, how can I go about it and interact with this device at kernel level if it only has user-space API?

You can download the code at

- For Linux :
  https://www.xilinx.com/Attachment/Xilinx_Answer_65444_Linux_Files.zip
- For Windows : https://www.xilinx.com/Attachment/Xilinx_Answer_65444_Windows_Files.zip

Comment: Take the I/O facing portion of the existing driver and add your own kernelspace API to it; make sure your **entire project** respects all applicable licenses!

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you! That's exactly how I did it. I just opened the third-party driver as a file inside my Linux driver and got access to it.